# Incorporate ruby parameters into string raises bad url error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure what I'm doing here

```
def get_full_stats(id)
        riot_url = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/#{id}/ranked?api_key=mykey'
        response = HTTParty.get(riot_url)
        json = JSON.parse(response.body)
        json
    end
```

and in my show.html.erb I am calling the following

```
api = RiotApi.new
@info = api.get_full_stats(19380406)
```

the view is returning to me `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` for the `@info = api.get_full_stats(19380406)` line.

I tried casting the parameter as a string  `@info = api.get_full_stats('19380406')` but still raises the same error.

What's going on here?

After restarting the server, it appears that I now have a `URI::InvalidURIError` Error instead.

Comment: Can you post all the code for the `RiotApi` class?  From what you've presented, it looks like it should be working.

Comment: RiotApi class only contains def_full_stats, which is why I am confused too. If I hard code the id portion of the url in, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: the error changed to bad url after I restarted the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for string interpolation to work.  For example,

```
def get_full_stats(id)
    riot_url = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/#{id}/ranked?api_key=mykey"
    response = HTTParty.get(riot_url)
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    json
end
```